# How to set variable reuse back to False in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorlfow, we can set variable reuse to `True` with `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()`, is there any way it to set it back to False without leaving the scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. In the tutorial on Sharing Variables, they explicitly state:

> Note that you cannot set the reuse flag to False. The reason behind this is to allow to compose functions that create models. Imagine you write a function my_image_filter(inputs) as before. Someone calling the function in a variable scope with reuse=True would expect all inner variables to be reused as well. Allowing to force reuse=False inside the function would break this contract and make it hard to share parameters in this way

You have to get out of your scope and open another with the same name and `reuse=False`

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is the following:

```
print tf.get_variable_scope().reuse
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True): 
  print tf.get_variable_scope().reuse
  # Code that reuse variables goes here
print tf.get_variable_scope().reuse
```

output:

```
 False
 True
 False
```

So just put the parts of code where you need to reuse variables inside the `with`.